# The cylinder led on my desktop is on and it’s res

Tags: led

I upgraded my cpu so I had to take apart most of my pc. When I put it back together there was a cylinder and lightning bolt led light that I’ve never seen turn on before. The cylinder is on and it’s red and the other is blue. I switched the power supply and the cpu and it had the same problem and I still get no display when I turn it on

Comment: what is the make and model of your PC? Please [edit] and add this essential information to your question.

Comment: The cylinder LED means the harddisk has activity. The lightning bolt is the power indicator. It seems you connected cables that were previously disconnected, so this is expected behavior. They are now turned on, but there is a different problem preventing boot. Don't focus on the LEDS for now unless you ruled everything else out. Normal behavior for these leds are: power led, always on, hdd led only on when there is activity, so should blink or be off.